# $\int f(z)dz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

a) let $f$ be a holomorph function on $\{z:|z|>1\}$. Show that the value of $\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz$ is independent of $r$ for $r>1$.

b) Suppose, More over, that $f$ satisfies $|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1}{|z|^2}$. Show that $\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz=0$ for all $r>1$

**My attemp for (a):**
Let $z=|z|e^{it}$ whrer $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. We have
$$\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{it})rie^{it}dt$$

**My attemp for (b):** we have $r>1$ so $r^2>1$ and then $\dfrac{1}{r^2}<1$. So

\begin{eqnarray*}0\leq |\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz|&\leq& \int_{|z|=r}|f(z)|.|dz|\\
 &\leq& \int_{|z|=r}\dfrac{1}{|z|^2} |dz|\\
 &=& \int_{|z|=r}\dfrac{1}{r^2} |dr|\\
 &\leq& \int_{|z|=r}1 |dr|
\end{eqnarray*}
Now how I can get the result?

Comment: See [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Proof)

Comment: For a), differentiate your integral wrt $r$ and prove it to be constant. For b) make the polar coordinate substitution and you can prove that the integral gets no greater than $2\pi /r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\times \times \times$ (a) For each $r >1$, $f$ is holomorphic on the ring $A: 1 < |z| < r$, thus by Cauchy integral theorem $\int_{\partial A} f\, \mathrm dz =0$, which implies
$$
\int_{|z| =r} f \,\mathrm dz = \int_{|z| = 1} f\, \mathrm dz,
$$
i.e. the result is independent on $r$.

(b) By (a), for each $R > 1$,
$$
0 \leqslant \left\vert \int_{|z| = 1} f \,\mathrm dz  \right\vert = \left\vert \int_{|z| = R} f\, \mathrm dz  \right\vert \leqslant \int_{|z|=R} |f| |\mathrm dz | \leqslant \int_{|z| = R} \frac {|\mathrm dz|} {|z|^2} = \int_{|z| = R} \frac {|\mathrm dz|} { R^2} = \frac {2\pi R}{R^2} = \frac {2\pi}R \xrightarrow {R \to +\infty}  0, 
$$
hence the conclusion.

#### UPDATE

Part (a) may not be an applicable case for Cauchy integral theorem, since the theorem only deals with those simply connected region $U$. A weaker version would also require that $f$ is of $\mathcal C^1$ on $\overline U$. Thus the "solution" of (a) above is controversial.

The solution of part (b) still works, since $\int_{|z| = r} f\, \mathrm dz$ is independent on $r > 1$, hence the inequalities and the limiting process still work, except that the integral is not $\int_{|z| = 1} f \,\mathrm dz$ shown above, whose existence is questionable under the assumption given.